# Ubuntu 14.04 slow refresh rate (slow in general) Lenovo t60 4GB RAM Intel® Core™ Duo CPU T2400 @ 1.83GHz × 2

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, ram

My Lenovo T60 runs very slow on version 14.04.  All the research on this website is quite old and I am wondering which version of Ubuntu I should be using ... from system monitor it is not using the CPU 12% and mem @34% ... not using and swap space. Are there any suggestions to get this old machine to run better using Ubuntu? It is running 32 bit and shows only 3GB memory even though it has 4GB installed.Intel® Core™ Duo CPU T2400 @ 1.83GHz × 2. would a SSD make it faster?
I connect my second monitor VGA 22" and it runs very much slower.

Comment: It's a 10 years old business oriented notebook currently at Amazon (used) with a price tag of $89 (+ shipping). Performance expectations should be set accordingly. That said, it should still perform acceptably with standard Unity and a little better with Xubuntu/Lubuntu. The graphics chipset here is very important. Please add yours https://support.lenovo.com/es/en/documents/migr-62722#vid . Also the HDD, if old, could be failing.

Comment: And a note from Lenovo: *Only 64-bit operating systems support more than 3GB of system memory (RAM). Intel Chipsets 945GM and 945PM do not support more than 3GB system memory (RAM), even when a 64-bit operating system is installed.* Perhaps better to keep the original configuration, 3GB (2+1).